# On Android loss of WiFi connection does not lead to connection termination, but loss of mobile data network does. Why?

Tags: android, smack

- I am testing loss of network connection on android Galaxy S6 for my app.
- I have two types of network 1) WIFI 2) mobile data
- I establish a stream from device to server.
- I use SMACK to establish the stream

---

- I do two types of tests:
- First I disabled WIFi before I launch my app. That means I only launch with mobile data enabled.
- While in app, I switch to **"Airplane Mode"**
- I observe my stream is close with error "Connection Closed on error" triggered by loss of network.

---

- Second, I launch my app only with WIFI (I disables mobile data before launching app)
- I repeat the same test case as above switching to **"Airplane Mode"**
- But this time, the app/smack library did not detect loss of connection and I see not errors related to network.

Can you please explain the discrepancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Android kernels do not close the TCP socket in certain cases. Also it depends on how Airplane mode is concretely implemented.

Comment: then, in such cases smack reconnection manager will not work. So, should I rely on failed ping(s) or CONNECTION_CHANGE notifications to re-establish the stream by explicit disconnect and explicit connect?

Comment: The answer is simple: You should do both. Use Smack's `ServerPingWithAlarmManager` API to perform an scheduled server ping once in a while and listen for `CONNECTIVY_CHANGE` intents. Then use `XMPPTCPConnection.instantShutdown()` do terminate the connection but keeping the Stream Management state and reconnect.